# css issue typing in this text area and only allow 1 button to be selected per row

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am fiddling with a bootstrap set of buttons. It does a good portion of what I am trying to accomplished, but now I realize that I cannot type in the text area and I also, want if I toggle a button on this row, the others should toggle off. This is leveraging bootstrap 4- so I am brand new to this.Any idea of why I can't type in the text area and how to allow only 1 button on at a time.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off">Option A <br>Able to appreciate working 
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off"> Option B<br>
               <textarea></textarea>
        </label>
     
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off"> Option C <br>Able to eat food
        </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to only allow one button to be selected at once, change the checkboxes to radio buttons like so:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked /> Active
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" /> Radio
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" /> Radio
  </label>
</div>
```

In regards to the textarea, the bootstrap JavaScript is interfering with it as it hasn't been designed to have such elements included.  You can move the textarea out of the label and it should work.  This would require some additional styling to make it look like you want.

```
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off">Option A <br>Able to appreciate working 
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off" /> Option B<br>

        </label>
     <textarea></textarea>
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" name="options" autocomplete="off"> Option C <br>Able to eat food
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: the first set does not work as requested. I want if one button is selected, the other two to toggle off. What you have done--doesnt work. Its like they are stuck

Comment: Your input tags are not well formed.  They need to be self closing with a `/>` at the end. And remove the active class off them (except the one you want initially selected).

Comment: @ Steve Taylor yes I have, but active needs to toggle on to the one that is selected. It does not

Comment: I've done a quick codepen showing it working.  The top one is from the bootstrap docs:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/buttons/#button-plugin

And the bottom one is from your example.

Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/stevetayloruk/pen/JgdeMX

Comment: @ Steve Taylor is there a way to ensure the width of the box remains a certain size regardless of how short or long the text is..is tried min-width="400px" but it doesn't work

Comment: just updated the codepen with a style added to the btn class with min-width.  Is this what you mean? you may want to create a new class though as this would affect all buttons.